# Trouble Joining an Active Directory Domain

Tags: windows, samba, dns, active-directory

I'm trying to join an Ubuntu 16.04 server to a Windows 2003 R2 domain by following the [Ubuntu SSSD and Active Directory Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/sssd-ad.html). My admin says that from the controller side, it is part of the domain. But SSSD can't seem to start and `net ads join` fails.

The `krb5.conf` was modified by the installer and now has this:

```
kyle@Server21:~$ cat /etc/krb5.conf
[libdefaults]
        default_realm = COMAPNYNAME.LOCAL
```

On a previous install I thought there was something else in `[realms]` that was asked for during the install but I can't remember what and it wasn't asked for this time around.

My `smb.conf`:

```
[global]

## Browsing/Identification ###

# Change this to the workgroup/NT-domain name your Samba server will part of
   workgroup = COMPANYNAME
   client signing = yes
   client use spnego = yes
   kerberos method = secrets and keytab
   realm = COMPANYNAME.LOCAL
   security = ads
```

My `sssd.conf`:

```
kyle@Server21:~$ sudo cat /etc/sssd/sssd.conf
[sssd]
services = nss, pam
config_file_version = 2
domains = COMPANYNAME.LOCAL

[domain/COMPANYNAME.LOCAL]
id_provider = ad
access_provider = ad
override_homedir = /home/%d/%u
```

Though the SSSD service can't seem to start:

```
kyle@Server21:~$ systemctl status sssd.service
● sssd.service - System Security Services Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/sssd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2016-06-22 09:57:57 EDT; 37min ago
  Process: 16027 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sssd -D -f (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jun 22 09:57:55 Server21 sssd[16038]: Starting up
Jun 22 09:57:55 Server21 sssd[16041]: Starting up
Jun 22 09:57:55 Server21 sssd[16042]: Starting up
Jun 22 09:57:56 Server21 sssd[be[16043]: Starting up
Jun 22 09:57:57 Server21 sssd[be[16043]: Failed to read keytab [default]: No such file or directory
Jun 22 09:57:57 Server21 sssd[16031]: Exiting the SSSD. Could not restart critical service [COMPANYNAME.LOCAL].
Jun 22 09:57:57 Server21 systemd[1]: sssd.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jun 22 09:57:57 Server21 systemd[1]: Failed to start System Security Services Daemon.
Jun 22 09:57:57 Server21 systemd[1]: sssd.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jun 22 09:57:57 Server21 systemd[1]: sssd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

And since the guide says that ownership and permissions are important:

```
kyle@Server21:~$ sudo ls -la /etc/sssd
total 12
drwx--x--x   2 sssd sssd 4096 Jun 21 14:34 .
drwxr-xr-x 103 root root 4096 Jun 22 10:21 ..
-rw-------   1 root root  172 Jun 21 14:22 sssd.conf
```

My `nsswitch.conf`:

```
kyle@Server21:~$ cat /etc/nsswitch.conf
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         compat sss
group:          compat sss
shadow:         compat sss
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files sss
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis sss
sudoers:        files sss
```

My `hosts`:

```
kyle@Server21:~$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       Server21.COMPANYNAME.LOCAL Server21
192.168.11.11   Server21.COMPANYNAME.LOCAL Server21

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Here is where the trouble starts. Using `sudo` to run `kinit` results in the following:

```
kyle@Server21:~$ sudo kinit adminstrator
kinit: Client 'adminstrator@COMPANYNAME.LOCAL' not found in Kerberos database while getting initial credentials
```

It will authenticate if I drop the `sudo` though:

```
kyle@Server21:~$ kinit -V administrator
Using default cache: /tmp/krb5cc_1000
Using principal: administrator@COMPANYNAME.LOCAL
Password for administrator@COMPANYNAME.LOCAL:
Authenticated to Kerberos v5
```

And I can verify the ticket:

```
kyle@Server21:~$ klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000
Default principal: administrator@COMPANYNAME.LOCAL

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
06/23/2016 13:41:55  06/23/2016 23:41:55  krbtgt/COMPANYNAME.LOCAL@COMPANYNAME.LOCAL
        renew until 06/24/2016 13:41:48
```

But when I try to join the domain:

```
kyle@Server21:~$ sudo net ads join -k
Failed to join domain: failed to lookup DC info for domain 'COMPANYNAME.LOCAL' over rpc: An internal error occurred.
```

I had previously received the `NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL` message mentioned in the guide but was able to solve that by modifying my `hosts` file.

The guide talks about verifying that the computer account was created in the Active Directory. And my admin says that he can see the machine just fine so I believe that is okay. The second verification option does not tell me what I'm supposed to get back from that command but I don't receive anything so I suppose it isn't working.

So where am I going wrong here?

---

**Edit:**

I'm not sure what I did, but SSSD is now running.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 used upstart, not systemd. That output is fishy.

Comment: @muru Sorry for the typo. I'm on 16.04. Question has been edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to have been that my admin had created an entry on the Domain Controller for this server. This apparently caused a conflict that caused Kerberos to encounter the following error when trying to join:

```
kyle@Server21:~$ sudo net ads join -k
Failed to join domain: failed to lookup DC info for domain 'COMPANYNAME.LOCAL' over rpc: An internal error occurred.
```

I'm not sure that this error was entirely accurate since my admin said the server was joined to the domain on his end and `realmd` indicated that I was joined as well:

```
kyle@Server21:~$ realm join COMPANYNAME.LOCAL
realm: Already joined to this domain
```

The steps I followed to get a successful Kerberos join were as follows:

1. Admin removed the entry in the Domain Controller
2. Reran Kerberos configuration using: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure krb5-config`
3. Chose the options in the configuration to add the Domain Controller explicitly to the `[realms]` section of `krb5.conf`
4. Changed the hostname to ensure a new record was created
5. Pulled a new ticket using `kinit`
6. Joined the domain using `sudo net ads join -k`

Final result:

```
kyle@SERV21:~$ sudo net ads join -k  
Using short domain name -- COMPANYNAME  
Joined 'SERV21' to dns domain 'CompanyName.Local'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the keytab. You can create it via kadmin tool. type *kadmin* and in the prompt type *help* to see how to add the keytab.

Comment: `/etc/krb5.keytab` already exists and has some encrypted stuff interspersed with the server name and domain name. Do I need to create an additional one?